# Zend_Db: How to connect to a MySQL database over SSH tunnel?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, ssh

How can I connect to a MySQL database that requires an SSH tunnel using PHP and the Zend Framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just start up SSH tunnel and use the local port as your MySQL port.

For example, you start tunnel as this,

```
ssh -f user@mysql-server.com -L 3306:mysql-server.com:3306 -N
```

And you can connect to MySQL like this,

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

For zend_db, you do this,

```
$config = new Zend_Config(
    array(
        'database' => array(
            'adapter' => 'Mysqli',
            'params'  => array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'dbname'   => 'my_db',
                'username' => 'mysql_user',
                'password' => 'mysql_password',
            )
        )
    )
);

$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);
```

Comment: I'm getting a "connection refused" message. It's also saying that it's connecting on port 22 which doesn't make sense since I am specifying the two ports...do you know why this isn't working for me?

Comment: The error means you don't have SSH running on the server. It has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: ah, turns out it was an issue with the way I was connecting via ssh.