# PDO and SSH2 tunnel

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, pdo

Is there any way to connect to database using PDO and SSH tunnel and do not execute any code at command line like in the topic below?

[Zend_Db: How to connect to a MySQL database over SSH tunnel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807118/zend-db-how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-over-ssh-tunnel)

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without invoking the ssh tunnel within a seperate process, that means you will have to create a new tunnel for each invocation of the script - and you can't share an tunnel created by another instance since you don't know when it will terminate. So in addition to the connection overhead you need to manage a pool of local sockets.

The short answer is that it's just not feasible.

A longer answer is that you can start daemons/long running processes from within PHP but [there are a few caveats](http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html). So if you can use the program execution functions and have access to a set of POSIX tools using the command line tools then it is possible. It'll be a lot simpler to implement this if you can set up a key pair (with an necryted private key) to avoid having to parse the I/O to the program to inject the password at the right point (or use something like '[expect](http://debaan.blogspot.com/2007/09/simple-expect-ssh-example.html)' to handle it).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this using a combination of `ssh2_tunnel`, `socket_create_listen()`, and `pcntl_fork`. Basically the tunnel is what we want to use to connect to the port on the MySQL box, but because PDO doesn't support connecting via a socket we have to create a port via `socket_create_listen` on a dedicated php fork that just pumps data from the unix socket to the ssh tunnel.

```
PDO (php main proc) -> random socket port on 127.0.0.1 -> data proxy (php fork proc) -> ssh2_tunnel resource -> ssh server -> mysql process.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the steps?

Answer (score 0):

If you have php with ssh2 extension, it should be possible.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-tunnel.php