# How to close this ssh tunnel?

Tags: mysql, macos, ubuntu, ssh

I opened a ssh tunnel as described in this post: [Zend_Db: How to connect to a MySQL database over SSH tunnel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807118/zend-db-how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-over-ssh-tunnel)

But now I don't know what I actually did. Does this command affect anything on the server?
And how do I close this tunnel, because now I can't use my local mysql properly.

I use OSX Lion and the server runs on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Assuming you ran this command: `ssh -f user@mysql-server.com -L 3306:mysql-server.com:3306 -N` as described in the post you linked.

A breakdown of the command:

1. `ssh`: that's pretty self-explanatory. Invokes `ssh`.
2. `-f`: (From the `man ssh` page)

   > Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.
   >            This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or
   >            passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.

   Essentially, send `ssh` to background once you've entered any passwords to establish the connection; it gives the shell prompt back to you at `localhost` rather than logging you in to `remote-host`.
3. `user@mysql-server.com`: the remote server you'd like to log into.
4. `-L 3306:mysql-server.com:3306`: This is the interesting bit. `-L` (from the `man ssh` page):

   > [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
   >            Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be
   >            forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.

   So `-L 3306:mysql-server.com:3306` binds the *local* port `3306` to the *remote port* `3306` on host `mysql-server.com`.

   When you connect to *local* port `3306`, the connection is forwarded over the secure channel to `mysql-server.com`. The *remote host*, `mysql-server.com` then connects to `mysql-server.com` on port `3306`.
5. `-N`: don't execute a command. This is useful for "just forwarding ports" (quoting the man page).

> Does this command affect anything on the server?

Yes, it establishes a connection between *localhost* and *mysql-server.com* on port *3306*.

> And how do I close this tunnel...

If you've used `-f`, you'll notice that the `ssh` process you've opened heads into the background. The nicer method of closing it is to run `ps aux | grep 3306`, find the `pid` of the `ssh -f ... -L 3306:mysql-server.com:3306 -N`, and `kill <pid>`. (Or maybe `kill -9 <pid>`; I forget if just `kill` works). That has the beautiful benefit of **not** killing all your other `ssh` connections; if you've got more than one, re-establishing them can be a slight ... pain.

> ... because now I can't use my local mysql properly.

This is because you've effectively "captured" the *local* `mysql` process and forwarded any traffic that attempts to connect to it, off to the *remote* `mysql` process. A *much nicer* solution would be to **not use local port 3306** in the port-forward. Use something that's not used, like 33060. (Higher numbers are generally less used; it's pretty common to port-forward a combination like this: "2525->25", "8080->80", "33060->3306" or similar. Makes remembering slightly easier).

So, if you used `ssh -f user@mysql-server.com -L 33060:mysql-server.com:3306 -N`, you'd then point your Zend connect-to-mysql function to `localhost` on port `33060`, which would connect to `mysql-server.com` on port `3306`. You can obviously still connect to `localhost` on port `3306`, so you can still use the local `mysql` server.

Comment: Best explanation I read in a while. This is very useful when accessing a remote database from locally installed environments like R for example. Works well with public / private key authentication. Not with passwords because I did not find a way to pass the passwords.

Comment: Accepting this answer as best because of the thorough explanation.

Comment: Nice answer! By the way, `-9` is not needed for `kill`, considering the process is still working fine ;-)

Comment: is there a official way to stop it? instead of the regular kill?

Comment: This is the [code](https://replit.com/@KaushikDonthi/Killing-Process-Code#main.sh) for what @simont described

Answer (score 69):

This will kill all ssh sessions that you have open from the terminal.

```
sudo killall ssh
```

Comment: 'No matching processes were found' it says.

Comment: It seems like it is. Mysql worked fine as well, but then Apache started to complain. I did a reboot and everything works as expected. Issue resolved I guess :)

Comment: Well you do not want do this if it is a prod environment... you will kick out all other admins

Comment: Running `killall ssh` is a rather reckless command. I advise searching your process list (i.e. `ps aux | grep ssh` as suggested by @simont above) to discover the specific process id of your ssh tunnel process. Then you can kill pid that specifically.

Comment: There is a good chance you won't want all of them killed.

Comment: @Ben It's worth mentioning that the process executing `ps aux | grep ssh` will also list itself

Answer (score 27):

Note: adding as answer since comments don't support code blocks.

In my opinion it is better to NOT use `-f` and instead just background the process as normal with `&`.  That will give you the **exact** pid you need to kill:

```
ssh -N -L1234:other:1234 server &
pid=$!
echo "waiting a few seconds to establish tunnel..."
sleep 5
... do yer stuff... launch mysql workbench whatever
echo "killing ssh tunnel $pid"
kill $pid
```

Or better yet, just create this as a wrapper script:

```
# backend-tunnel <your cmd line, possibly 'bash'>
ssh -N -L1234:other:1234 server &
pid=$!
echo "waiting a few seconds to establish tunnel..."
sleep 5
"$@"
echo "killing ssh tunnel $pid"
kill $pid
```

`backend-tunnel mysql-workbench`

`backend-tunnel bash`

Comment: Using `-f` allows the `ssh` session to continue even when the terminal session is closed, unlike pushing to background. Grabbing the `pid` using `ps aux | grep ssh | grep <LOCAL-PORT>` is pretty trivial.

Comment: @simont using the explicit pid returned from the background job is safer, regardless of how you background it. if you have more than one ssh process running _you're gonna have a bad time_

Comment: Using `-f` also has the advantage of prompting the local user for the login password, if needed. If you use `&`, that prompt is not seen by the user unless they bring the process to the foreground (e.g. by using `fg`).

Comment: See also [Opening and closing an SSH tunnel in a shell script the smart way](https://gist.github.com/scy/6781836)

Comment: @simont `ps aux | grep ssh | grep <port>` was **exactly** what I was looking for. I've tried so many other ways that never worked. Turns out the simplest way _can_ be the best way :)

Comment: the first time your <LOCAL-PORT> occurs in the pid of a process which also contains the text 'ssh' (such as another ssh or sshd process or editing a file with 'ssh' in the name) you'll realize that this approach, while convenient in simple scenarios, is not bulletproof